# Django queryset join tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am really stuck with merging two tables.

I have tables Item and Transactions

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category_choices = []
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=category_choices)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

class Transactions(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.UUIDField()
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transactions')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_str = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_plz = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[(name[1], name[1]) for name in countries])
```

Now I want to render template with transactions and images and items info from Item model. I am trying to use prefetch_related, howeve rit does not work and I do not understand how this should be solved.

```
def order_history(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        transaction = Transactions.objects.order_by('-transaction_date').\
            filter(username=request.user).prefetch_related('item')

        context = {'orders': transaction}
        template_name = 'retail/order_history.html'
        return render(request, template_name, context=context)
    else:
        raise Http404('You are not authorised')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your transactions table, name your Item column `item` instead of `item_id`:

```
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transactions')
```

Then your `prefetch_related("item")` will work as expected.

Comment: but it doesnt make a lot of sense from database point of view. I am thinking now about just using sqlalchemy to fix this

Comment: Django ORM deals with Python objects.  It doesn't make sense to refer to an "Item" as an "item_id" -- Item ID is just an attribute of the Item object.  Internally Django respresents it as item_id in the database table.  It's a foreign key that references your Item table.

Comment: changed it, but didnt help, I am still getting an error, that attribute from table Item does not exist  `>>> Transactions.objects.order_by('-transaction_date').filter(username='admin').prefetch_related('item')[0].username
'admin'
>>> Transactions.objects.order_by('-transaction_date').filter(username='admin').prefetch_related('item')[0].stock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Transactions' object has no attribute 'stock'
`